# Asana - Query members of a team

Tags: javascript, asana

Is it possible to query the members of a team in Asana?

I can query the users in a workspace, but I need to get a more specific group of users.

The only other way I can think of is to get the team members to follow a specific project, but ideally I'd like to avoid this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet supported, but I'll add a vote for it to our API project!